# How we can create non admin user who will have limited privilages to database?

Tags: couchdb

I am new to CouchDB, as I am learning it for the first time which is required in our upcoming project so while learning CouchDB I want to create a non-admin user who will have limited access to a database

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html?highlight=security#authentication-database) where the Authentication Database is described.

It is required to create a doc in the _users database

```
curl -X PUT http://<host>:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:new-user \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"name": "new-user", "password": "apple", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
```

[Here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html?highlight=security#authorization) it is described the authorization mechanism. Each DB allows to roles, admin or member. A member can read and write content in a DB whereas an admin has the privileges of members plus the privileges: write (and edit) design documents, add/remove database admins and members and set the database revisions limit. They can not create a database nor delete a database.